# what is the best way to visualize data for 56 us states and number of universities in them using seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, data-mining

i have a dataset and i have already visualized it using bar graph but it has 56 inputs in x axis , it makes it hard and does not look good in visualizing data . i am attaching sample bar graph i generated.

[image: bar graph i generated]

Comment: Looks pretty good to me though.

Comment: You could put the states on the y-axis and make the plot longer.